# Git: How can I list the changed files in a commit, including the SHA-1 hash for each file (blob)?

Tags: git

## What I Want, Summarized:

I have a commit, such as `HEAD` or `111abc111`, and I want an elegant way to print all of the modified files and *only* the modified files along with their SHA-1 hashes. How can I do that?

Below is an idea using `git-cat-file` that *almost* works, but it either lists all files (including files that didn't change) or you must use it in batch mode. Using it in batch mode initially seems promising, but I cannot make it work. See below for things I have tried with `git-ls-tree` and so on.

For a note about my priorities, see below in this question, or see the answer I wrote myself (which I am not going to accept, but maybe you can refactor it).

## Concrete Example:

**Setting up the example:**

For background, let's see what my Git working tree looks like:

```
$ ls

alice.txt
bob.c
carol.h
main.c

$ git status -s

# Nothing prints, the working copy is clean and untouched.
```

I will now change *only* two files:

```
$ echo "Add one line." >> bob.c

$ echo "Add one line." >> carol.h

$ git add .    # Add (stage) both changed files.

$ git status -s

M  bob.c
M  carol.h

$ git commit -m "Two changed files."

[master 111abc111] Two changed files.
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

---

**This does ALMOST what I want:**

```
$ git cat-file -p 111abc111:./

100644 blob 99c2e88ad312f1eac63afc908f64c370fac9d947    .gitignore
100644 blob 607f8ea764981fb3f92a8d91abc2b154d99bc39c    alice.txt
100755 blob 5a297bd6931c1a70abbcab919815324258c08b0f    bob.c
100644 blob c6c2dfd18d26c1cf71b21e9d4c0892157dd6ec33    carol.h
100755 blob d0802cd238a3e83f186bc5c24be7e23dfc69205f    main.c
```

The problem with the command above is that it lists everything at the specified path, which was `./` in this example, which is the current directory. It lists **every file**, not only the modified files. I only want it to show `bob.c` and `carol.h`.

A second problem is that using `111abc111:./` to specify the tree-ish object will only show files (blobs) in that one directory, it will not show files in subdirectories. Subdirectories will show up like this:

```
040000 tree b98f38763b689e8197c6129726d41169fceeaaa0    subdir
```

**Possible Ideas:**

I just deleted a few paragraphs with some things that I have tried.

I suspect the key will be using `git-diff` to make a list of "git objects" (including blobs) that have changed in the specified commit, and then pass that list of "git objects" in some format to `git-cat-file`. So a magic command like this might work:

```
$ git diff 111abc111^ 111abc111 --magic-options-go-here | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objectsize)'
```

The key is to find the value for `--magic-options-go-here`. I am also not convinced `git-cat-file` is what I want on the right side of the pipe character, I might want something else.

Thank you.

### Edit: My Priorities

I am more interested in "git objects", the entities stored within Git and identified by SHA-1 hashes, such as trees, blobs, commits, and maybe other things I have not thought of such as tags. I am far less interested in filenames and how things actually look in the filesystem if you do a checkout of the commit.

I want to see the SHA-1 hashes so that I can see "oh, this merge commit is pointing to the tree from *way over there* in a different branch." With branching and merging and rebasing in a large repository, each commit object contains a huge number of trees and blobs that have not changed and are just pointers (references), and the things they refer to may get very far away in a conceptual sense. This can become apparent when you change just one line, do a git-commit, then do a git-push and the amount of data pushed is 50 MiB. Internally, Git just had to dereference a ton of pointers and make new deltas and packfiles and stuff. Things that feel like small changes in the working directory (the filesystem) may actually represent a lot of data in the Git repository binary format.

Comment: Can't you get most of what you need using `git diff --raw`?

Answer (score 4):

simple like that:

```
git show --stat --name-only 'YOUR_COMMIT_HASH'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
git diff --stat --name-only $COMMIT^ $COMMIT \
  | xargs git ls-tree --full-tree  $COMMIT
```

This can be put into an alias:

```
# Usage: git changed-files <commit>
# List files changed in a commit.
git config --local --add alias.changed-files '!f() { git diff --stat --name-only $1^ $1 | xargs git ls-tree --full-tree  $1 ; }; f'
```

Here's an example of the output from one of my repos:

```
$ git changed-files d3a3029ca7489cb168d493de3d695809e84ffb0f
100644 blob 39855d9b6918f1c02f33115e357d7beeed1aaab8    libstdc++-v3/ChangeLog
100644 blob d0257c07e1fe92da339512d2457ac2ad43b12686    libstdc++-v3/include/std/optional
100644 blob 86b58ccf225597a64995878edc68c8666fa2c675    libstdc++-v3/include/std/type_traits
100644 blob 020cb26453f465ac49afb87f77e4833d0fb3aa16    libstdc++-v3/testsuite/20_util/optional/cons/value_neg.cc
```

It could be enhanced to show the changes between two arbitrary commits when given two arguments:

```
# Usage: git changed-files <commit> [<commit>]
# List files changed in a commit (or between two commits).
git config --local --add alias.changed-files '!f() { git diff --stat --name-only ${2:-$1^} $1 | xargs git ls-tree --full-tree  $1 ; }; f'
```

Comment: Thank you, this works in very simple cases, and it definitely does work sometimes. I'm slightly surprised that `xargs` is working on paths with spaces in them, at least for me on one platform. This is not really a git-based solution, which is possibly fine, but probably less portable. It has limitations due to not using `git-cat-file`, for instance it cannot show the size of the blob (the -s option). It also seems somewhat breakable with respect to renames and deleted files.

Comment: The fundamental limitation is that your pipe is passing **only** filenames, it is not actually passing "git objects", which can be more meaningful and which can preserve the actual logical relationship between blobs, trees, commits, and deltas. Using `git-diff` correctly will either follow or not follow renames, for instance.

Comment: With GNU xargs you can use `xargs --delim=\n` to break on the newlines between each filename, ignoring spaces, but that makes it less portable. For POSIX you can do `xargs -I %@ git ls-tree --full-tree $1 %@`. But if you want a pure-git solution you're going to have to write one yourself working at a much lower level.

Comment: My solution seems to do everything you asked for in your question ("I want an elegant way to print all of the modified files and only the modified files along with their SHA-1 hashes"), but I'm not sure how to improve the answer now that you're moving the goalposts!

Comment: I don't intend to move the goalposts, I think I didn't express the original question clearly enough. I added my own terrible hackish answer to emphasize my priorities. Your solution is great for the narrowest definition of "modified files", which is not added, not deleted, not renamed, not renamed and rewritten by 90%, and so on. It is modified files, passed by filename. My hackish answer (which I am also not about to accept) is the opposite approach, it is deeply based on git objects and comparing the objects that comprise two commits.

Answer (score 0):

## Very Ugly Answer from OP:

If I need to accept this answer, then I will be sad. But I wanted to write it, because I have thought of it:

**Step 1: Do git-ls-tree on $COMMIT^1**

```
$ git ls-tree -r $COMMIT^1:./
```

This will give you a long list of every single file and directory in the tree-ish for that commit. The `-r` option makes it recursive, so it shows every single file and directory.

Store this output somewhere.

**Step 2: Do git-ls-tree on $COMMIT**

```
$ git ls-tree -r $COMMIT:./
```

Again, store the output somewhere.

**Step 3: Write a Python script to delete all unchanged lines**

Taking the two (very large) STDOUT dumps from above, write a Python script that deletes lines if and only if they have a SHA-1 that appears in both `$COMMIT^1` and `$COMMIT`.

Anything where the SHA-1 appears in both is a 'git object' that did not change at all. Anything where the SHA-1 did change, whether or not the filename changed, and whether or not it is a file (or a tree, or a tag, or something else I didn't realize could exist), if the SHA-1 changed or is new, this is a change between `$COMMIT^1` and `$COMMIT`.

This is super hackish but it will not miss any changes of any kind. It may over-report changes, slightly.

If nobody has a magic Git-based answer, then I may actually write this Python script and post it here.

Comment: Using Bash and GNU join and GNU sort, something like: `join -j 3 <(git ls-tree -r $COMMIT^:../ | sort -k 3) <(git ls-tree -r $COMMIT:../ | sort -k 3 ) -v 1`

Comment: That's a fine suggestion, but I would personally use Python and then use `set` objects. I like writing Python, it is very portable, and `set` objects are exactly the right thing. The answer I want is the `xor` of two sets. (If I use this terrible hack solution.)

Comment: Sure, and it would be more flexible in the end, but I had written that pipeline before you've even started your Python version, so it works as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem lies in defining "modified" objects: modified *with respect to what?*  Each commit is a snapshot; a snapshot does not tell you what *changed*.  To find changes, you must pick some additional snapshot.

Using `git diff` with two commit (or tree) hashes gets you an answer: modified between those two hashes.  Using `commit^` means you're comparing a commit to its immediate predecessor, which is usually the right answer for ordinary commits.  It's more problematic with merge commits, as they have—by definition!—two or more immediate predecessors.

Note that if you want to convert a potential commit or annotated-tag hash to a tree hash (to identify top level tree hash IDs), `git rev-parse` is the way to go: `git rev-parse $hash^{tree}` verifies that whatever object `$hash` identifies, it can be followed to the point of finding a tree object, and then `git rev-parse` emits the tree's hash ID.  This is useful for detecting whether `git merge` was run with `-s ours`, for instance: if so, the tree hash of the merge commit matches the tree hash of the merge commit's first parent.  See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for myriad spellings for specific operations, such as `^{}` to find the object underlying a tag object (regardless of the type of the underlying object) vs `^{commit}` to find the commit and fail if it's not a commit.  These suffix operations work with most valid syntax, but not with `:/search`, so it's sometimes wise to use a two step process: resolve some arbitrary user-provided string to a hash first, then use `${hash}${suffix}`.

Having found the object(s) you want, perhaps including or stopping at top level tree objects, you can indeed use `git ls-tree` (with or without `-r` for recursion).  But now, having defined what you mean by "modified", you must choose what kinds of modifications count as "modifications".  For instance, what if the difference between commits P and C is just that the *mode* of file `path/to/script` went from `100644` to `100755`?  Or, what if `path/to/script` *was* a regular file, and is now a symbolic link?  What if if some path used to name a file, but is now a directory full of files, or vice versa?

You can use `--name-only` or `--name-status` with `git diff`, for instance, and by using `git diff` with `-M`, you can enable Git's "tree-wide" *rename detection* code.  But now it is worth considering that `git rev-parse` and `git ls-tree` are *plumbing* commands, that behave in a well-defined and scriptable manner.  On the other hand, `git diff` itself is *not:* it is a so-called *porcelain* command, so it obeys per-user and per-repository configurations.  This means that `git diff` in repository A might find renames by default while `git diff` in repository B might not.

That in turn means that if you are looking at `git diff` as a possible tool, you should look instead at the plumbing variants: `git diff-files`, `git diff-index`, and `git diff-tree`.  If you've already made the choice to compare trees attached to commits, `git diff-tree` is the clear winner here.

It's a bit painful to use, but it is designed to be script-driven, and from Python in particular you can run `git diff-tree` with the `-z` and `-r` options, and read the output as a series of `b'\0'`-separated records.  Note that `git diff-tree` will automatically use a regular commit's parent commit as the first of the two inputs:

```
$ git diff-tree -r HEAD
b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f
:100644 100644 2b45b6ff5cb3bf2980ad911b8c84179f27d8d72c f2e261abf38dba4e608de1ca40a805f2b0e3818c M      Documentation/RelNotes/2.19.0.txt
```

For a merge commit, however, `git diff-tree` defaults to doing a *combined diff*, in which files that are unchanged from either parent are suppressed.  To avoid this, either feed `git diff-tree` two explicit hashes (commit or tree hashes), or use `-m` to split the merge into multiple virtual commits, each with a single parent, and get diffs against each parent.

Answer (score 0):

The direct way to do it is `--raw` format, `git show` does exactly the human-ifying you want, it combines diffs against all parents:

```
$ git show --pretty= --raw @^
::100644 100644 100644 d1ab6625f6 dfb6c554ac 00abe95315 MM      builtin/commit-graph.c
::100644 100644 100644 f013a84e29 417b7eac9c 3da52847e4 MM      commit-graph.c
::100755 100755 100755 9bf920ae17 786b5f73ef 117dca317e MM      t/t5318-commit-graph.sh
::100755 100755 100755 53b2e6b455 e2017bc24b 6dda4c1f1c MM      t/t5324-split-commit-graph.sh
$
```